# Date Field showing as text due to the '-' hyphens present in the field.How to handle this and show as date in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So ,I have a date field in date format (Jan-17) and when I filter on that field it keeps showing Text Filters as below instead of date

[image]

Requirement is to get Date Filters as below :

[image]

One thing I noticed is that when I remove the hyphens(-) which are rows without any date ,it then shows as Date .
How can I show this column as Date including the hyphen rows as well?

Comment: If date field is showing as text one easy way is to use `Text To Columns` from the `Data` tab and convert to `MDY` option so that it works as true dates.

Comment: Hi. I tried that as well but it has no effect on the column at all.Still shows as text.

Comment: So have you checked whether it has any non breaking characters or not?

Comment: How to check that ?I selected delimiter as tab for text to column

Comment: repeat the same process of doing with Text to columns and check the 2nd step. until and unless you change the text to column 2nd step will show what you have used for delimiter

Comment: I tried this but didnt find any non breaking character but still shows as text.

Comment: Also I have similiar column with hyphens but it is showing as Date correctly without any modifications required.

Comment: From your last statement, if removing the hyphens it shows as dates then use the following as custom format: `m/d/yyyy;[=0]"-";`

Comment: Some countries, notably US, do not follow a D-M-Y or Y-D-M date format. What is your system date format and what is the data format in the file? If the two are different, a few methods are possible to fix it.

Comment: My date format is dd-mm-yyyy and format of the system is US based so it is having M-D-YYYY format

Comment: Changing date format to the custom one given also did not solve the issue

Comment: Will I able to attach the excel if possible?

Comment: I have uploaded the file at below link :https://fastupload.io/WsD1bibMg3nQlUW/file. In That file the first column is having the issue ,while the 3rd column with similiar date format and hyphen does not have the issue and shows correctly as date filters

Comment: Please check my latest comment

Comment: Sorry I am not going to download it says virus infected.

Comment: anyways is there any other portal for file sharing then?

Comment: Can you please try this link: https://file.io/DxbBSIgWgFDv

Comment: I am still not going to download sorry, once it alerted abt, virus, i cannot take risk anymore. sorry

Answer (score 1):

I was able to download your file without getting a virus warning.
I'm not sure why your column C is working .

However, your formatting for Column A is not doing what you think it is. The cells which are displaying `-` contain an actual `-`.

If you leave the formatting the same, and, using the `Find/Replace` tool, replace all of the hyphens with 0's, the filter will now show Date filters and not Text filters.

Perhaps it has to do with the large number of hyphens in the column, relative to the real dates.

You will note that the 0's formatted as hyphens will now show the hyphens on the right, not the left.

Also, in the filter dropdown, the cells that appear as hyphens will be shown as the date `1900`

[image]

Comment: Sir strange that you have not got any pop up for virus using the first link. Have you downloaded the second link using.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I downloaded from the second link and no warning. Scanned it with AVAST and no problem. Then allowed editing.

Comment: Ok, I was using the first link when `Kaspersky` gave me a warning or virus infected. Hence i didnt dare to download the second. BTW Sir, which antivirus is good to use for computer

Comment: Thank you for going through the file. I tried the same steps of find and replace and it is working .But actually this file is to be sent to a client and he is asking why the 3rd column is working and expects the same format of the file throughout ,which is why I am confused as this are exports of same snowflake source.